# Find last run defrag WMI or Reg key

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, wmi

I am trying to discover if there has been a defrag run on our servers.  To save myself going to each one and loading the defrag program and checking the "Last Run" column I thought WMI might have this info.  I have been checking the Win32_Volume class and can see this can be used to initiate defrags and run the analysis.  What I can't find is any reference to the last time it completed.  I would rather just pull an object down than run an analysis each time.  Is there a way to find this information through WMI or a reg key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a query for Event ID 258 in the Application event log

```
PS F:\ps1> get-winevent -filterHashTable @{Logname = 'Application'; ID = '258';} | select-object -first 1 -prop machinename,timecreated,message | fl

MachineName : coyote.acme.com
TimeCreated : 9/24/2014 2:28:07 AM
Message     : The disk defragmenter successfully completed defragmentation on (C:)
```

Comment: Didn't think of that.  Had to go with Get-EventLog in the end as the defrag messages will not display for Get-WinEvent which I can't fathom.  My method is much slower but it has to run overnight which is no great hardship.  At least then I will have something!  Probably have a followup question about the blank messages object soon lol

Comment: IIRC get-eventlog came with an earlier version of PS and can query events from remote targets of any OS including older OS's like 2003. Get-WinEvent came with a later PS, operates more quickly/efficiently, but requires the remote target be 2008 (R2?) or later.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already have an answer to this. But you might look at the question a little differently if you wanted to use the DefragAnalysis.

```
$driveLetter = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'"
$driveDefrag = $driveLetter.DefragAnalysis()
$driveDefrag.DefragAnalysis
```

`$report.DefragRecommended` will display if the OS thinks it needs a defrag and `$report.DefragAnalysis` has a lot of additional useful information as well.